# Error "could not find article that just added to db: 5576330055082049537" posting share to LinkedIn

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I'm having problem posting a share to LinkedIn from my Android application. I'm using the library [Linkedin-j](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/) for Android. I'm encountering the error "could not find article that just added to db: 5576330055082049537" when attempting to share with the status code of 400.

The XML request body that Linkedin-j is sending is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<share>
<content>
<title>The quick brown fox jumped jumper over the lazy dog </title>
<submitted-url>http://www.mywebsite.com/</submitted-url>
</content>
<visibility>
<code>connections-only</code>
</visibility>
</share>
```

I've successfully requested and retrieved a valid oAuth access token and I can post a status updates. But I can't post shares.

I've tried this on a two different API accounts and have the same issue. I've also tried adding the comment field to the request but this had no effect.

I've checked over the documentation here https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api# and can't see that I'm doing anything wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it is a bug in LinkedIn share api see [discussion](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/error-could-not-find-article-just-added-db-5576330055082049537-posting-share)
it works for me for shortened links so I'm now using bitly to shorten the link if it fails

Comment: apperantly i haven;t noticed you opened the thread in the linkedin developer board, sorry...

Comment: Hehe, that's a discussion I started! Glad they have admitted there is a bug I was starting to pull my hair out trying to work out what I down wrong.